# Mouse down Issue

Tags: jquery, onmousedown

HI,

I am making my own scroll bar. in which i made this code below i pasted.  i am getting the issue from this code.

i) in the first time i am pressing "#scroller" that works fine.

ii) in case of second or other time when i am enter into "#scroller" itself, i am getting the alert "hi", instead of i am pressing the "#scroller", i know that i am doing some wrong this with my code, but i unable to find the mistake.

Any one help me?

$(function(){
    var slidesWidth = ($('#show-content li').length)*($('#show-content li').width()+20);

```
$('#show-content ul').width(slidesWidth);

var scrollBarWidth = (100/slidesWidth)*1000;//presently taken by manual/

$('#scroller').width(scrollBarWidth);

$('#scroller').bind('mousedown',function(){

      $('#scroller').mousemove(function(){
            alert('hi');        
        }) 

})

$('#scroller').bind('mouseup',function(){

      $('#scroller').unbind('mousedown,mousemove');
      alert('unbinded');

})
```

})

Comment: you might want to add additional tags (like jquery) to get more folks looking at this

Answer (score 1):

`#scroller`'s `mousemove` event may not have been unbound. Try this when you [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

```
$('#scroller').unbind('mousedown').unbind('mousemove');
```

Comment: it is cancel the total mouse down and move, i unable to switch back to events, what we need.